# python script to remove reversed repeated lines

Tags: python, bash

I got a python code that removes lines if they are similar when reversed. For example if I have a document that contains:

```
1,2 3,4
5,6 7,8
2,1 4,3
5,6 8,7
```

After executing the script, the output is

```
5,6 7,8
2,1 4,3
5,6 8,7
```

Consider first column is 1,2 and second column is 7,8 for a line then, if another line contains reversed values for each column as 2,1 AND 8,7 this is considered as reversed.

However, i noticed that the script doesn't keep the order of the lines. The lines order are important for me. Also, I need to remove the second similar reversed line, not the first one.The code is

```
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1]) as inf:

    keys = set()

    for line in inf:

        ports, ips = line.split()

        port1, port2 = ports.split(",")

        ip1, ip2 = ips.split(",")

        if ip1 < ip2:

            keys.add((ip1, port1, ip2, port2))

        else:

            keys.add((ip2, port2, ip1, port1))

with open('results', 'w') as outf:

    for result in keys:

        outf.write("{1},{3}\t{0},{2}\n".format(*result))
```

Any ideas? Any suggestion if we can do it on bash scripting?

Thanks

Comment: Are `1,2 7,8` and `7,8 1,2` equivalent?

Comment: This doesn't look like any definition of "reversed" I've ever seen. What problem are you actually trying to solve? Why do you need this script?

Comment: no.consider first column is 1,2 and second column is 7,8 for the a line then if another line contains reversed values for each column as 2,1 AND 8,7 this is considered as reversed.

Comment: @user2566898 checkout my solution, is that what you wanted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `collections.OrderedDict` here:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> dic = OrderedDict()
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        key = tuple(tuple(x.split(',')) for x in line.split())
        rev_key = tuple(x[::-1] for x in key)
        if key not in dic and rev_key not in dic:
            dic[key] = line.strip()
...             
>>> for v in dic.itervalues():
    print v
...     
1,2 3,4
5,6 7,8
5,6 8,7
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned `bash`, here's an `awk` solution

```
awk -F'[ ,]' 'BEGIN{OFS=","} {$1=$1};
!($0 in arr){print($1,$2" "$3,$4);arr[$2","$1","$4","$3]}' file.txt

1,2 3,4
5,6 7,8
5,6 8,7
```

Comment: +1 This is nice. Always pleasing to see `awk` still capable challenging `python`.

Comment: @JS웃 , thanks! It's solutions from yourself, Kent, Glenn Jackman et al that have opened my eyes to the power of awk.